# Sideflow.js GotoIf how do I use conditionals

Tags: selenium-ide

I've been working on three different ways to solve this.  What I do know is the EASIEST way hopefully would be to do the following.

Form Field 1 (ignore syntax, I'm just setting up an example here) the id= is the important part in the two form fields.

```
<select name="select" id="pick_animal" value="">
  < option="the fast cat" id="1">
  < option="the fast dog" id="2">
</select>
```

Form Field 2

```
 <input type="text" id="some_animal" value="the fast cat from dover">
```

I need to detect that id="some_animal" contains cat so I can perform an action on the correct option in field 1. I can do the second part just fine, I just can't detect "cat" in only the input with id "some_animal" storeTextPresent just looks for cat to exist anywhere on the page. ugh!!
one way I can see to solve this would be to do the following.

```
storeValue | id=some_animal | value_some_animal
gotoIf | ${value_some_animal} contains "cat"   | my_cat_label
runscript | (message here)
goto | end
label | my_cat_label
run some commands here.
label | end
```

so at the gotoIf statement, I need to do a conditional basically want to see if it contains
"*cat*", and I'm using the HTML Driver in selenium IDE, I would like to avoid selenium webdriver if I can help it.

```
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
<td> ${value_some_animal} ......</td>
    <td>target2</td>
</tr>
```

How would I have the gotoIf evaulate that it ***contains*** "cat", with javascript or any other method?

```
<td> '${value_some_animal}' == 'cat'</td>  <--- doesn't work
<td> '${value_some_animal}' == '*cat*'</td>  <--- doesn't work
```

etc....
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

storeValue | id=some_animal | value_some_animal

gotoIf | '${value_some_animal}'=='cat' | my_cat_label

runscript | (message here)

goto | end

label | my_cat_label

run some commands here.

label | end

Try like this, think it will be ok.

Thank You.

Comment: It won't work like that, because it doesn't equal cat.  I have tried that.

Comment: please try once more by avoiding goto|end  and label|end.

Comment: Nikhil, If I remove the goto | end, it will just run the code irregardless.  Defeating the whole purpose. I may as well remove gotoIf, and storeValue also.

Comment: Nikhil, I'm not sure if you understand what i'm trying to accomplish.  The code I included is a simple example for the purpose of this question.  But I definitely need evaulate that the input value contains cat,  == Wants the input value string to exactly match.

Comment: dont know whether it will correct for you please try this also   gotoIf | ${string} = 'string number two' | lableA